# A better disassembler than `objdump -d`?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly

I notice when using `objdump -d`, it outputs the assembly (in either Intel syntax or AT&T syntax), the binary opcode encodings and the address numbers. In my case, I just want the disassembler to just output the AT&T assembly as it is irritating to remove the first 18-24 characters (yeah, didn’t count that) to copy assembly from one object file to an assembly file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can anyone help?

Yes! `man objdump` can. Look for AT&T (<kbd>/</kbd>AT&T<kbd>enter</kbd>)! then, `--no-addresses` *should* work.

You can pass your favorite assembler syntax mode using the `-M` option; in your case, `-M att`.

If you want a generally more versatile disassembler, try `radare2` (though it takes half an hour to get used to it).

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-addresses` flag mentioned in [Marcus Müller’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680399/86440) was introduced in Binutils 2.35. With older versions of `objdump` (Ubuntu 20.04 or older, RHEL 8 or older), you can obtain the same result by switching to the old disassembly output, with fixed-width addresses and no encoded instructions, and then trimming the output. On 64-bit platforms:

```
objdump -d --prefix-addresses ... | cut -c20-
```